# How do I search in multiple files with "cat"?

Tags: command-line, cat

What I want is to find within a directory all the files containing  a match and when it finds the match it shows the file where that match was found.

example

```
cat * | grep password:
```

Here it will show me all the matches that have a "password:"

But it doesn't show which file the match belongs to.

Comment: Why use `cat` when you can `grep` directly? You can use `grep -R "pattern" .` (`-R` would search for pattern recursively and `.` refers to current directory). If there's some other reason to use `cat`, please [edit] your question and explain that.

Comment: Note that `grep password *` will - by default - print the names of files in which matches are found *if `*` matches multiple files*. If you want it to print filenames unconditionally, add the `-H` (or long-form `--with-filename`) option

Comment: Why not simply use the -H option? for example grep 'password:'  -H -r  <path>  and for filenames only use -l option (instead of -H)

Answer (score 8):

I think it's not possible to get the filenames after you piped the result of `cat` like in your example, because the `cat` command will just concatenate the contents, the information about filenames is gone after that.

What you could do instead is to rely on the `grep` command's behavior when it gets multiple input files, then `grep` will show the filename for each match.

So, instead of

```
cat * | grep password:
```

you could do this:

```
grep password: *
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `cat` and `grep` to print out the names of files that contain the "password:" string within the current directory:

`cat * 2>&- | grep -ls 'password:' *`

With full file path:

`cat * 2>&- | grep -ls 'password:' ${PWD}/*`

`2>&-` is used to suppress error messages about being unable to read certain files/directories.

---

Using only `grep` to do the same thing:

`grep -ls 'password:' *`

With full file path:

`grep -ls 'password:' ${PWD}/*`

---

Using `grep` to pattern match for the "password:" string, printing the filename, then using `cat` to display the entire file(s) contents:

```
for match in $(grep -ls 'password:' *) ; do
    echo "${match}"
    cat "${match}"
done
```

With full file path:

```
for match in $(grep -ls 'password:' *) ; do
    echo -e "\e[7m\n$(readlink -f "${match}")\e[0m"
    cat "${match}"
done
```

Comment: The whole first section is *at best* misleading, since `grep` does not read from the pipe when used in this way. They're just immensely overcomplicated versions of the `grep`-only commands you show next. This is not, in any reasonable sense, *using* both `cat` and `grep` to do anything.

Comment: Regardless of efficiency, the poster was interested in seeing `cat` used.